# React-Query/SWR vs Global state (e.g Redux, Zustand) when updating a single post creator's details in an infinite list of posts

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-query, swr

In my application, I have a paginated feed containing posts retrieved from the /feed endpoint.

Each feed `post` has...

- `postId`
- `postTitle`
- `postBody`
- `postCreator` (object)

Each `postCreator` object has...

- `userId`
- `userName`
- `userBio`
- `userImageUrl`

[As suggested by Redux](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape#designing-a-normalized-state), I'm currently...

- Extracting the `postCreator` objects and storing them in their own global `usersStore` (using Zustand)
- Replacing the `postCreator` objects with the relevant `postCreatorId` (which references a user in the global `usersStore`) in each post
- Storing the posts in their own `postsStore` (using Zustand)

The benefits of this are...

- If a user updates their information (e.g. name or bio), we only have to update their record in the usersStore, and their information will be updated across the whole app (their post creator info in the feed posts UI, their profile image in the tab-bar etc)
- We don't have to re-request the data from the /feed endpoint to get the posts containing the updated `postCreator` object. Especially considering that a user may have scrolled way down the feed at that point in time, so we may have to get hundreds of posts from the /feed endpoint, putting strain on our backend.

**React-Query/SWR**

I have recently discovered React Query and SWR and have heard a lot about how they "remove much of the need for global state", but I'm slightly confused by how they handle the above scenario. After doing some research on React-Query, I'm under the impression that there a few ways to handle this...

1. Still use the global `usersStore` and `postStore` to update the user's information in a single place, as described above.
2. Scrap the global `usersStore`, and update the `postCreator` information directly in React-Query's cache for the `/feed` infiniteQuery, using `queryClient.setQueryData`. But we would have to also update the other query caches where the user's information is returned, and what if the cache has expired?
3. Scrap the global `usersStore`, and refetch all of the posts from the /feed endpoint when a user updates their info. However, if a user has scrolled way down the feed at that point in time, we may have to get hundreds of posts from the /feed endpoint, putting strain on our backend. [React-Query infinite query refetch docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/infinite-queries#what-happens-when-an-infinite-query-needs-to-be-refetched)

**What is the best practice way to handle this using React-Query/SWR?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

react-query doesn't have a normalized cache. That being said, mostly, there is no need to do any normalization - just keep what the api sends you as your state, retrieve it via `useQuery`, and get rid of all redux / zustand  global stores that would otherwise hold your server state.

In your example, I see two queries:

- `useQuery(['user', id])` for the user data
- `useInfiniteQuery(['feed'])` for the feed of posts

When rendering your `feed`, you'll likely render a `Post` component for each entry, which can in turn call the `useQuery` that retrieves the user data. If you are worried about the n+1 queries that are being made, and you are in fact already delivering the user-data with the feed, you can manually prime the user-cache in the `onSuccess` callback of the `feed` query - just take the user data and copy it to the user-cache.

That way, the user-cache becomes the single source of truth for user data, which also updates from the feed query.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, n+1 could be problematic. Re your second solution, you're suggesting we reference the user-cache for each postCreator when we render the feed? I guess the question is, as the user-cache is now no longer used to get async data from the backend (it's just used as a single source of truth to store user data), why is it preferable to just using a Redux/Zustand to store the user data? Unless you're also suggesting that when we get new user data (e.g when a user's profile is opened), we use useQuery(['user', id]) and update the existing user's record retrieved from the feed endpoint?

Comment: yes, when the profile page is opened, you can also just call useQuery(['user', id]) and profit from the fact that the cache is already pre-filled. This assumes that you have an endpoint that actually returns user data :)

Comment: Awesome! I'm going to give it a go and report back (and accept the answer if all is working as expected). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to confirm, I implemented this and it is absolutely the best solution!

Comment: So does that mean that if I have highly relational data RQ might not be for me? Seems like because RQ doesnt have a normalized cache, I could potentially double the in memory footprint of the cache by storing lots of duplicate data in that cache.

Comment: Timur, I'm not sure I understand your issue, could you explain a little further?